# What games can I play on a slow Internet connection?

Tags: windows-8, game

I have a internet connection of **512 Kbps to 1 Mbps**. Please suggest me games that work in multi-player or co-op even at this speed.

My hardware is not a bottleneck. The game should be playable. Please comment if you have played the game yourself, or just expect it to work at these speeds.

Sorry for this broad question, but one day this might turn into a wiki post. And will be helpful to people like myself who don't have a good internet connection.

OS: Windows 8.1 x64

Comment: What kind of game are you looking for?

Comment: Games which are fun to play.. :D So that includes a vast number of games.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking:

You want a good ping to play online. So if your connection is not only low bandwidth but also low ping, then playing online might be a bad idea per-se.

MMORPGs usually needs a lot more bandwidth, just due to the amount of data that needs transfered per second. World of Warcraft or Star Wars might be potentially unplayable. One MMO that can easily be played with low bandwidth is Anarchy Online. I love this game and highly recommend it. It does have a very high learning curve though. Eve Online can also be played with low bandwidth, but only if you stay away from very crowded systems and especially fleet battles. I played those 2 Games with an UMTS Stick.

First Person Shooters tend to have a very low bandwidth requirement, such as, but not limited to Counter Strike, Battlefield or the Quake Live, which was recently released on Steam. I would suggest trying Quake out, it is an awesome game.

What also needs low bandwidth are games that can be played via Email, such as Civilization IV or many chess programs.

Comment: I have a ping of about 100ms. Is that good or bad?

Comment: @rahulroy9202 The ping that matters is the one to the game server. Your general ping to google or so does not matter. Depending on where you live it might always be high, no matter your internet connection.

Comment: What is the acceptable range? For a FPS.

Comment: @rahulroy9202 Depends on the game. Most games nowadays interpolate data so you can get away with 100ms for example. Most older games don't do that and then I say up to 100ms is still playable. But you have to live with the fact that others can shoot you faster because their packets are arrive faster at the server.

Comment: What MMO needs bandwidth that a 512Kbps connection can't handle? Wow barely goes over 50Kbps except perhaps when zoning into a crowded area like city or an auction house.

Comment: @corsiKa Star Wars needs a lot more, same with Landmark and some others. Especially those with a lot of customization since they need to transmit item coloring for each player. But when you zone into a crowded city, you can easily lose connection in WoW with a low bandwidth connection (and subsequently having trouble logging back in). Been there myself and it is not really recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Some Steam games work well on slow connections. I used to play [Dota2](http://blog.dota2.com/?l=english) with a friend who had a 1Mbps internet connection without any lag. The first Dota (Worldcraft III map) definitely works on slower connection. I don't want to generalize, but it's worth testing other MOBA games as well.